# Postgresql crashed or failed?

Tags: postgresql

THis is the error I get when I do

```
sudo systemctl restart postgresql@9.5-main.service
```

> Job for postgresql@9.5-main.service failed because a configured resource limit was exceeded. See "systemctl status postgresql@9.5-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details."

Postgres is running in a Azure VM, Ubuntu boot.

And the status is failed.

Any idea on how to fix this please folks?

Sure , adding the content here for postgres log:

```
2019-05-15 10:31:24 UTC [6953-2] HINT:  The file seems accidentally left over, but it could not be removed. Please remove the file by hand and try again.
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
2019-05-15 10:33:02 UTC [7253-1] FATAL:  could not remove old lock file "postmaster.pid": Permission denied
2019-05-15 10:33:02 UTC [7253-2] HINT:  The file seems accidentally left over, but it could not be removed. Please remove the file by hand and try again.
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
2019-05-15 10:41:11 UTC [7949-1] FATAL:  could not remove old lock file "postmaster.pid": Permission denied
2019-05-15 10:41:11 UTC [7949-2] HINT:  The file seems accidentally left over, but it could not be removed. Please remove the file by hand and try again.
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
2019-05-15 10:55:07 UTC [9064-1] FATAL:  could not remove old lock file "postmaster.pid": Permission denied
2019-05-15 10:55:07 UTC [9064-2] HINT:  The file seems accidentally left over, but it could not be removed. Please remove the file by hand and try again.
pg_ctl: another server might be running; trying to start server anyway
2019-05-15 11:33:59 UTC [11923-1] FATAL:  could not remove old lock file "postmaster.pid": Permission denied.
```

Comment: Please show the contents of the `systemd` service file and the PostgreSQL log.

Comment: Sure , adding the content here for postgreslog :

Comment: Please add that to the question, don't add it as a comment.

Comment: Sure, added the postgres log.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Which systemd service file? Its ubuntu, so which is the location you wanted me to check. /usr/share/man/man5/systemd.service.5.gz is the only location comes while I search for systemd.service

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the permissions of files in your your PostgreSQL data directory are wrong.

First, check if PostgreSQL is running:

```
ps -f -u postgres
```

If PostgreSQL is already running, you don't have to start it.

If not, check the contents of your data directory:

```
ls -l /path/to/postgres
```

(Since this is Ubuntu, things are difficult. Part of your files are under `/etc`, the other under `/var`.)

All these files should be owned by user `postgres`. From the error message it looks like at least the file `postmaster.pid` isn't.

If it is only that file, remove it. If there are more, you need more extensive repair.

Try to figure out how things got to be that way.

Comment: Hi @Laurenz Albe, I checked if postgresql is running, but only postgresql@10 is running, I need postgres@9.5-main.service to run which is used by my application. I couldn't find the postmater.pid in my system, I tried " locate filename" and sudo rm filename to remove it,  so hope there!! Suddenly these things happnd. Yes all folders are owned by postgres I checked it. What to do here.

Comment: Inside /etc/ there are two folders, postgresql and postgresql-common. Postgresql is owned by postgres postgres, but I checked postgresql-common is owned by root. I think its there by default, i din change it or modified it,

Comment: Try to use `find` rather than `locate`.

Comment: Tried that too. No such file or directory it says.\

Comment: If there is no such file on the machine, you shouldn't get the error message either.

Comment: Yes, true. but Im getting the error also. Can't figure out this error. Really anoying.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Comment: You must have made a mistake, and there *is* a problematic `postmaster.pid` somewhere. Hard to diagnose remotaly. Find out where your `postgresql. conf` and your data directory is.

Comment: Sure @Laurenz Albe, I sure have figured it out. It was a update from Postgresql Made it reject the needed connc. Duno how it happnd thou. Thnx for your support here.